# SQLite: migration from FTS3 to FTS4

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts3, fts4

I have some project with SQLite database that already uses FTS3 extension.
Say I want to use FTS4 instead. 
What has to be done for that?
Is there need to create new tables, repopulate or anything else?
Or just change word 'fts3' to 'fts4' is enough?

Comment: The only place where the word `fts3` appears is the CREATE TABLE statement. Do you create a new table every time your program runs?

Comment: no, I do not create